# SSIS: Weird issue with a particular lookup

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, business-intelligence

I have an ETL project that I've developed using SSIS with Visual Studio 2015.  I have added a new dimension key column to one of my fact tables in my data warehouse, and needed to add the lookup in the data flow to grab the primary key from the appropriate dimension table.  I set all of this up, and it runs fine with no errors, but the results I'm getting are not correct.  Each row is getting populated with -1 for that column, which is what we default NULL values to with use of a derived column component.  I know for a fact these values are not NULL because

1) I checked the values manually using the same SQL that's in the source component both in SSMS and with the preview button in the source component.
2) I ran the package manually through visual studio and enabled the data viewer before and after the lookup, and both viewers showed the correct values for both the input column and the lookup column.
3) I changed from ignore failures to redirect rows to error output, and set up a flat file destination to print the input key to that is supposedly NULL, and the file showed all valid keys that I am expecting.

I've taken these keys and manually done lookups to my dim table just to verify that there is a match for the lookup columns and there is.  Here's the really weird part.  If I run the package alone, then everything works fine.  When I run the whole master package either through the catalog or through SQL Agent, that's when I get all -1 values.  I know there are no tasks further down the road that are modifying that value because I just added it to the table.  I can't figure out why all of my rows were getting redirected to the error output, but they were not NULL values.  If anyone has any suggestions on something different for me to try, I'm all ears/eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be silly, but are you possibly not mapping the right column in the destination or possibly not mapping at all?

Comment: Yes the mapping is correct. If I run the package by itself either through visual studio, or through the catalog then it populates correctly. I'm very close to just rebuilding the entire package from scratch to see if that fixes it, but I would really like to know what's causing the problem.